# Pass list of items from $.get() to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My `controller Action method` looks like the below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ShowModal")]
    public Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int id, string name, IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
    {
    //create a model
    //Some business logic codes

    return PartialView("_Partial.cshtml", model);
    }
```

I need to call the above Action Method from `jQuery's $.get()` method on a button click, capture the partial view returned as `HTML`, and show it in a Bootstrap popup.

I am not able to pass the `IEnumerable<Employee>` from the `jQuery` method, it is always `null`, whatever I try.

Below is the JS code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowModal();" data-keyboard="true" data-toggle="modal">ShowModal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="divShowModalDialog" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-body" id="divShowModalBody">
    </div>
</div>

function ShowModal()
    {
        var list = [{ Id: 101, Gender: 'MALE' }, { Id: 102, Gender: 'FEMALE' }];
        list = JSON.stringify(list);

        var data = { 'id': 999, 'name': 'JAMES', 'employees': list };

        $.get('/Area1/Controller1/ShowModal', data)
        .done(function (response) {
            if (response != undefined) {
                $('#divShowModalBody').html(response);
                $('#divShowModalDialog').modal(
                    {
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: true,
                    });                
            }
        })
        .fail(function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        })           
    }
```

I get the `id` and `name` parameter in the Action method, but the list is always empty. I have tried after removing `JSON.stringify()` as well, but it doesn't work. 
I know I'm missing a trivial thing, please help.

Comment: You could try changing `public Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int id, string name, IEnumerable<Employee> employees)` to `public Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int id, string name, List<Employee> employees)`.

Comment: @Keyur Patel: Are you sure about it?

Comment: @Anurag check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be using `[HttpPost]` on your controller action and not `[HttpGet]`, and of course you'll need to use post from jQuery which is using [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and that is because 'POST' is the correct - but not the only - [HTTP](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) verb to actually post data to the server side.

Second, you shouldn't stringify your employees list before you put it in your `data` javascript object that you are sending. 
so, <strike>`list = JSON.stringify(list);`</strike> and just straight away go

```
var data = { 'id': 999, 'name': 'JAMES', 'employees': list };
```

You also might need to provide the dataType using `$.post(url,data,onsucess,dataType)` check documentation in the link above.

Last, on your action method remove `IEnumerable<T>` and replace it with a concrete collection type like `List<T>` because the JSON serializer will need to know which type of collection to instantiate at binding time.

Comment: You are right. I just did the same thing, changed GET to POST in the action method and $.get() to $.post() in the jQuery method. Works fine. I don't think I need to change IEnumerable<T> to List<T>, coz List inherits from IEnumerable. Thanks

Comment: Even though List<T>  "implements" IEnumerable<T>, that is not the issue, the issue is how would the json converter figure out which type of collection to create that implements IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: I need not change IEnumerable<T> to List<T>. The JSON binder recognizes it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can achieve it without changing it to POST by using $.ajax()

Use a dictionary object instead of IEnumerable in action method

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(int id, string name, Dictionary<int,string> employees)
    {
```

And then in the script

```
var list = [{ Id: 101, Gender: 'MALE' }, { Id: 102, Gender: 'FEMALE' }];


    var data = { id: 999, name: 'JAMES', employees: list };
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetDetails',
        type: "GET",
        data :data,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it. But i have to use $.get() or $.post() not $.ajax(). They all are more or less same, but I need not use $.ajax().

Answer (score -1):

I was replying to your comment but decided it would be easier to demonstrate my point as an answer.

To answer your question, no I am not sure. But thats why I asked you to try it first, it seems logical as you are passing a `list` and not `IEnumerable` to your function.

Also, depending on what your `Employee` class looks like, you should try this: (you need a **constructor** in your Employee class for this)

```
List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
list.Add(new Employee(101, 'MALE'));
list.Add(new Employee(102, 'FEMALE'));

var data = { 'id': 999, 'name': 'JAMES', 'employees': list };
...
```

**Update**

I realize why I'm wrong, I kept thinking in C# terms. Json.stringify() returns a json style string (which C# just sees as a string), so your `public Task GetDetails(int id, string name, IEnumerable employees)` should be `public Task GetDetails(int id, string name, string employees)` and then in C#, you need to parse the JSON string. A helpful link: 
[How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: How can you create a List<T> as you have created above in JS? I don't think so. And List inherits IEnumerable, so those are okay.

Comment: @ Keyur: I can't just change the signature of the function mate. Thanks for your help. I will try to find out the solution.